# How to test symmetry of distribution in Python?

Tags: python, statistics

Given data I want to test symmetry of their distribution. In R is function symmetry.test(..) https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lawstat/versions/3.4/topics/symmetry.test, I tried to google all tests which are included in the documentation. Do you know some Python library in which is the symmetry test implemented or should I choose R instead of Python? :D Or implement it on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skewness is a measure of symmetry, thus you can implement a test using skewness.

Take a look at `scipy`
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skewtest.html